# CakePHP Model error callbacks from AJAX functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cakephp

Update

Controller code, but its very simple,

```
  public function AJAX_AddNewUser() {
    $this->layout = 'ajax';
    $this->loadmodel('User');
    $this->loadmodel('Level');

    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $this->User->create();
        if ($this->User->save($this->request->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Something good.', 'default', array(), 'good'));
            return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Something bad', 'default', array(), 'bad'));
        }
    }

    $levels = $this->Level->find('list', array( 'fields' => array('Level.id', 'Level.leveltitle') ));       
    $this->set(compact('levels'));
    $this->render('/Admin/User/ajax_addnewuser');
}
```

First off, I am in Cake 2.5.1 with JQuery 1.11 (I also have the UI, but not used here).

So in my admin view I have a button, which loads a from via AJAX a simple form to add a new user, this works, submits and adds the data without any error. However I have added into my CakePHP model so basic checks, like to make sure the user is unique. So when the admin submits the form the model 'error' messages are displayed within / on the ajax loaded user input form.

This more or less works, but it only works the 1st time, once the admin submits for a second go, the returned result is different. I am not sure here I found this code, some post on here, but I have the following,

```
    var AdminAddNewUser = function() {
        $('#UserAddNew').on('click', function() {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/PATH",
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "html",
                success: function(data) {
                    $('#UserTargetUpdate').html(data);
                    SubmitingNewUser();
                },
                error: function(fail) {
                    console.log(fail);
                }
            }); //End of AJAX function    
        });
   }

   var SubmitingNewUser = function() {
        $('#UserAJAXAddNewUserForm').on('submit', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            $.post($(this).attr('action'), $(this).serialize(), function(res) {

                var testString = res;
                console.log($(testString).find('div > .error-message'));

                if ( $(testString).find('div > .error-message') ) {
                    console.log( 'yes' );
                    console.log(res);
                } else {
                    console.log( 'no' );
                    console.log(res);
                }
            }) //End of post
        }) //end of 'on' submit
   }

   AdminAddNewUser();
```

First function, is my AJAX form which loads without fail, my user form. And then within the success callback, I load my 'replacement' code to display Cake's error model results.

Now with (as you can see) all the console logs I have been doing, I know what the problem is (or at lest I think I do), when the admin submits the from for a second time, the result in 'res' var is a full page of HTML code, I think it loads the default path that all users get on login.

So why work only once? I have added the ajax function that load the user form in the before filter, so that the security functions inside Cake don't do anything to it.

Buy I am a little at a lost here, if it works once, why fail or returned different results the second time around?

If I have not explained myself right or I have missed anything, code etc, then please let me know so I can post more details.

Many thanks,

Comment: show controller code?

Comment: controller code now posted. I did think about that after I posted but its the same more or less as all my other ajax functions. I think its something to do with the JQuery code.

Comment: use  exit; at the end of function...

Comment: I'm pretty sure the redirect will cause problems once it's triggered... anyways, so what does the response actually contain? You think it's "_the default path that all users get on login_", whatever that means, but have you actually inspected it?

Comment: Yes - (i think I have fixed it, I will post that in another comment) but to answer your comment ndm, yes I did, and when I submitted the first time, I got HTML code with the form back in it with the models errors but the second time, I just get back the HTML code from the default path for the user.

Comment: I do seem to have fixed it, but use .html rather than .replaceWith - it all seems to work fine. The only problem I have now, is displaying an ok message or clearing the from once its done, but that should be ok. ndm your right, when I got it to work, it reload the whole page. I just want it to refresh once ok and to load the flash message but I could do that with Jquery (i think?) - But many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, so this is my final code, which seems to work,

```
  var SubmitingNewUser = function() {
        $('#UserAJAXAddNewUserForm').on('submit', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            $.post($('#UserAJAXAddNewUserForm').attr('action'), $('#UserAJAXAddNewUserForm').serialize(), function(res) {
                var FormString = res;

                if ( $(FormString).find('div > .error-message').size() == 0 ) {
                    $('#UserAJAXAddNewUserForm').html('ok user saved!');
                } else {
                    $('#UserAJAXAddNewUserForm').html(res); //Add form back with errors from model
                }
            }) //End of post 
        }) //end of 'on' submit
   }
```

For now all I do is replace the user add form with a simple text message which I will style later.

Thanks for all your help.